# MongoDB update array of documents and replace by an array of replacement documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, go, mongo-go

Is it possible to bulk update (upsert) an array of documents with MongoDB by an array of replacement fields (documents)?

Basically to get rid of the for loop in this pseudo code example:

```
for user in users {
  db.users.replaceOne(
      { "name" : user.name },
      user,
      { "upsert": true }
}
```

The [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) documentation only documents the following case where all documents are being updated in the same fashion:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   <query>,
   { $set: { status: "D" }, $inc: { quantity: 2 } },
   ...
)
```

I am trying to update (upsert) an array of documents where each document has it's own set of replacement fields:

```golang
updateOptions := options.UpdateOptions{}
updateOptions.SetUpsert(true)
updateOptions.SetBypassDocumentValidation(false)
_, error := collection.Col.UpdateMany(ctx, bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$in": names}}, bson.M{"$set": users}, &updateOptions)
```

Where users is an array of documents:

```json
[
{ "name": "A", ...further fields},
{ "name": "B", ...further fields},
...
]
```

Apparently, `$set` cannot be used for this case since I receive the following error: Error while bulk writing *v1.UserCollection (FailedToParse) Modifiers operate on fields but we found type array instead.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`Collection.BulkWrite()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.BulkWrite).

Since you want to update each document differently, you have to prepare a different [`mongo.WriteModel`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#WriteModel) for each document update.

You may use [`mongo.ReplaceOneModel`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#ReplaceOneModel) for individual document replaces. You may construct them like this:

```
wm := make([]mongo.WriteModel, len(users)
for i, user := range users {
    wm[i] = mongo.NewReplaceOneModel().
        SetUpsert(true).
        SetFilter(bson.M{"name": user.name}).
        SetReplacement(user)
}
```

And you may execute all the replaces with one call like this:

```
res, err := coll.BulkWrite(ctx, wm)
```

Yes, here we too have a loop, but that is to prepare the write tasks we want to carry out. All of them is sent to the database with a single call, and the database is "free" to carry them out in parallel if possible. This is likely to be significantly faster that calling [`Collection.ReplaceOne()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.ReplaceOne) for each document individually.