# How would I update multiple records based on different key in Mongo in one query?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

If I have something similar to the following...

```
collection.InsertMany(context.TODO(), []interface{}{
   bson.M{ "_id" : 1, "member" : "abc123", "status" : "P" },
   bson.M{ "_id" : 2, "member" : "xyz123", "status" : "A" },
   bson.M{ "_id" : 3, "member" : "lmn123", "status" : "P" },
   bson.M{ "_id" : 4, "member" : "pqr123", "status" : "D" },
   bson.M{ "_id" : 5, "member" : "ijk123", "status" : "P" },
   bson.M{ "_id" : 6, "member" : "cde123", "status" : "A" },
} )
```

Is is possible to apply the following update in one InsertMany query?

```
[{"_id" : "1", "status" : "P0-A0"},
 {"_id" : "2", "status" : "P0-A1"},
 {"_id" : "3", "status" : "P0-A2"},
 {"_id" : "4", "status" : "P0-A3"},
 {"_id" : "5", "status" : "P0-A4"},
 {"_id" : "6", "status" : "P0-A5"}]
```

If so, how would that be done with golang?

Specifically, using `collection.UpdateMany(context.TODO(), filter, update)`, what would I have for my `filter` and `update`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the updated `"status"` just the string `"P0-A"` appended with the value of `"_id"` minus 1?

Comment: @rickhg12hs the status could be any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a single [`Collection.UpdateMany()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.UpdateMany) call, because you can't apply different update documents on different matched documents. You would have to call `Collection.UpdateMany()` many times, once for each different update document.

If you want to do it efficiently, with a single call, you may use [`Collection.BulkWrite()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Collection.BulkWrite). You have to prepare a different [`mongo.WriteModel`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#WriteModel) for each document update.

Here's how it could look like:

```
wm := []mongo.WriteModel{
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "1"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A0"}}),
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "2"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A1"}}),
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "3"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A2"}}),
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "4"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A3"}}),
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "5"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A4"}}),
    mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": "6"}).SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "P0-A5"}}),
}
```

There's too much "repetition" in the above slice literal, you can capture them using a helper function:

```
create := func(id, newStatus string) *mongo.UpdateOneModel {
    return mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().
        SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": id}).
        SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": newStatus}})
}

wm := []mongo.WriteModel{
    create("1", "P0-A0"),
    create("2", "P0-A1"),
    create("3", "P0-A2"),
    create("4", "P0-A3"),
    create("5", "P0-A4"),
    create("6", "P0-A5"),
}
```

Also if there's logic in the update which you can easily define, use a loop instead of listing all the elements:

```
var wm []mongo.WriteModel
for i := 1; i <= 6; i++ {
    newStatus := fmt.Sprintf("P0-A%d", i-1)
    wm = append(wm, mongo.NewUpdateOneModel().
        SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": strconv.Itoa(i)}).
        SetUpdate(bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": newStatus}}),
    )
}
```

And you may execute all the updates with one call like this:

```
res, err := coll.BulkWrite(ctx, wm)
```

See related: [MongoDB update array of documents and replace by an array of replacement documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159623/mongodb-update-array-of-documents-and-replace-by-an-array-of-replacement-documen/68159870#68159870)

Comment: Thank you @icza. I had not thought about the bulk write.